# iOS Emulator Error "Failed to launch the simulator: Array index is out of range" During Compile/Deployment (MT1008)

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin-studio

Everytime I hit the debug button in Xamarin Studio on the Mac, I get the following error:

Starting iPhone Retina (4-inch) simulator 7.1 Failed to launch the simulator: Array index is out of range. error MT1008: Failed to launch the simulator: Array index is out of range.

This seemed to start happening after I updated Xamarin in Windows and tried to launch the simulator via Visual Studio and the build host. Since then, I cannot launch it on Xamarin Studio on the mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning and rebuilding the project fixed it for me.

or reset the emulator and restart the emulator and it'll work.